# .EXE installer crashes when installing Python modules: IPython, Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython, pandas

I have recently installed `numpy` due to ease using the exe installer for Python 2.7. However, when I attempt to install IPython, Pandas or Matplotlib using the exe file, I consistently get a variant of the following error right after the installation commeces (pandas in the following case):

pandas-0.8.0.win32-py2.7[1].exe has stopped working

The problem caused the program to stop working correctly: windows close the program and notify whether a solution is available.

NumPy just worked fine when I installed it. This is extremely frustrating and I would appreciate any insight.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you download the .exe file? From PyPI?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. It works if you right click and 'Run As Administrator'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when I tried to install Pandas from source. Attempting to install it via `pip` didn't work either.

However, installing it via `easy_install` worked like a charm!

So just remove all traces of Pandas from your Python installation and run:

```
easy_install pandas
```